# How can I limit text score with $gt operator in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, nosql

I want to limit text scores using the $gt operator.

Using the find function, I can sort the text scores according to the text similarity status from largest to smallest. I can get the cursor with the highest score by putting a limit of 1 on the rank.

```
deneme = user.find(
   { '$text': { '$search': "dogan can" } },
   { 'score': { '$meta': "textScore" }})
    
deneme_sort  = deneme.sort([('score', {'$meta': 'textScore'})]).limit(1)
```

But I don't want the ones whose text score is below the value I gave, to be listed.

For example, I don't want text scores below 1.5 to appear in the list. I'm trying to use the '$gt' operator for this but I'm getting an error.

```
deneme = user.find(
   { '$text': { '$search': "dogan can" } },
   { 'score': { '$meta': "textScore"}},  {'score': { '$gt': 1.5 } })


TypeError: skip must be an instance of int
```

it gives this error because the find function can only take two values.

I'm trying to query using the '$and' operator. This time it does not recognize the '$meta' operator. Or the '$gt' operator must take two values.

```
deneme = user.find({ '$text': { '$search': "dogan can" }} ,
    {'$and':[{ 'score': { '$meta': "textScore" }},{'score': { '$gt': 1.5 }}]})

doc = []
for doc in deneme:
    print(doc)

Expression $gt takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Expression $gt takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.', 'code': 16020, 'codeName': 'Location16020'}
```

I just started learning mongodb. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're requesting is documented [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/#match-on-text-score). In short - you will need to use the aggregation framework so that you can have 3 stages to accomplish each of the following:

1. Perform the initial `$text` searching in a `$match` stage
2. Persist the text score as part of the document via an `$addFields` stage
3. Use an additional `$match` stage to perform the `$gt` filtering against that new score field.

Given a collection with the following documents:

```
test> db.foo.find()
[
  { _id: 1, key: 'dogan can' },
  { _id: 2, key: 'dogan' },
  { _id: 3, key: 'can' },
  { _id: 4, key: 'abc' }
]
```

A text search against `dogan can` will return the first three documents:

```
test> db.foo.aggregate([ { $match: { $text: { $search: "dogan can" } } },{$addFields:{score:{$meta:'textScore'}}}])
[
  { _id: 3, key: 'can', score: 1.1 },
  { _id: 1, key: 'dogan can', score: 1.5 },
  { _id: 2, key: 'dogan', score: 1.1 }
]
```

Appending the final `$match` (using a filter of `1.2`), only one of the documents is returned:

```
test> db.foo.aggregate([ { $match: { $text: { $search: "dogan can" } } },{$addFields:{score:{$meta:'textScore'}}},{$match:{score:{$gt:1.2}}}])
[ 
  { _id: 1, key: 'dogan can', score: 1.5 } 
]
```

If desired, you can of course include a `$sort` stage on the score as well.

Comment: thanks it seems useful. I will try this. but I don't want the text score to persist in the database. In the project I am developing, there will be maybe 5 thousand searches per second. This means that the permanent text scores are constantly changing. It would be great if the text scores are not permanent. I'll try and see.

Comment: This approach doesn't update/persist the score in the database. It just (dynamically) adds it to the output when retrieved. Also, if you don't even want to _show_ the score then you can append a `$project` stage to remove it as the last part of the pipeline, eg `{ $project: { score: 0 } }`

Comment: Yes, I saw that it is not permanent. I also added the limit and sort operators. It was exactly how I wanted it. Thank you very much. So glad I have you!